# How to save image in sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, blob, android-image

Well, I was wondering if it is possible and what the best method for saving images in database android (sqlite).
I read something about BLOB, but did not quite understand.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: store the path of images in the database.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273008/android-save-images-to-sqlite-or-sdcard-or-memory. reason you should store it on SDCard instead of database.

Answer (score 2):

You can, but you shouldn't.

Theoretically everything can be stored in a DB. But not everything is ideally stored in a database.

See it the other way: There is an old and long tested Database which is build and optimized for storing images: It's called "Filesystem".