# Android Storing RSS feed parsed data in a database for offline use

Tags: android, database, sqlite, rss-reader

I am parsing a Rss feed using sax parser in android. I am able to display the data online when net is connected but i also want it to work for offline use and update it when it gets connected again to internet / wifi. I have no clue how to go about it.

What should be my best approach now ? should i construct Sql database ? considering i have images as well. 
Or there is any other simpler way. I would prefer simpler way.

I need some further suggestion on the Sql database approach here, First : My rss feeds gives image url links which i diplay using bitmap and insutstream at runtime but now for offline purpose i need to save complete images like whatsapp does right ? is this right ? if yes how to save complete images in database ? And last i want to save the complete database on sd card not in internal memory , storing data on sd card will work fine or it will create problem ? because whatsapp stores quite a data in internal memory !! if storing on sd card is not a problem how do i store complete data on sd card ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on how long you want the data to persist.  Ask yourself:

Should this data be available to the users after rebooting the phone, or after force closing the app?  Should it be available regardless of the last time I had connectivity, as up to date as possible given that?

In that case, then yes - you should use a database.  Android has a number of built in helper classes for sqlite databases.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Which should get you started.

The images are pretty straight forward as you'll just stash a reference to the image(s) in the db.  You would of course write these images to disk as well (on the sd card or some other place...)  See:

[Save bitmap to location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/save-bitmap-to-location)

Your other options, afaik are:

1)  SharedPreferences (not really suited to this).

2)  Serializing your data and writing out/reading in from some file.

If you're still looking for more information on Database concepts and Android, here is a very good tutorial on the topic:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: can u share a better implementation of the database code ? which shows reading and writing to database from my List of objects . My java object "Data" is like:

public class Data {
  
    private String discount;
    private String location;
    private String name;
    private String Image;
    private String Description;
 
}
I get a list of these objects after parsing.

Comment: I would recommend you read the linked android documentation, as that covers the topic very thoroughly and has plenty of sample code to get your going.

Comment: Added a link to a good db tutorial that gives you a more complete code picture than the docs.

Comment: Also will it be fine to use shared preferences ?  i have a list of about 100 resturants with their location name description and image link .

Comment: I wouldn't recommend Shared Preferences, it's not really suited to this task in my opinion.  You could use it for this, but your data is complex enough that Key/Value pairs aren't really the best modeling technique imo.

Comment: I need some further suggestion on the approach here First : My rss feeds gives image url links which i diplay using bitmap and insutstream at runtime but now for offline purpose i need to save complete images like whatsapp does right ? is this right ? if yes how to save complete images in database ? And last i want to save the complete database on sd card not in internal memory , storing data on sd card will work fine or it will create problem ? because whatsapp stores quite a data in internal memory !! if storing on sd card is not a problem how do i store complete data on sd card ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357668/how-to-store-image-in-sqlite-database

For storign direct to database, but this isn't a good idea.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273008/android-save-images-to-sqlite-or-sdcard-or-memory/9273045#9273045

For the better choice