# Android ~ Listview with images that have been uploaded by user?

Tags: android, user-interface

I know how to setup a listview to have an image and some text on each rows.

I know how to have the user open up a dialogue to pick an image from the file system or live.

I almost know how to downsample it in case its huge. (too many ways, no expert to recommend one).

I really need to know how the user can create db entries (notes) that contain text and an image that is user selected. In essence, the user is entering text and selecting/uploading an image that makes a 'note' and the notes get displayed in a listview.

I don't want the full code, but rather a general direction. I did some research and for me its a big forest. If you can give general directions how thats done, I'll do the rest.

Thank you,

Comment: It is recommended to not store the image in the db it is better to store it on the filesystem and load the image from the saved path in the database. Just have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273008/android-save-images-to-sqlite-or-sdcard-or-memory/9273045#9273045.

Comment: Hey thanks Lunero. Yes, I understand now the reasons why this is better. Thanks again.

Comment: Do you want the image with notes to be saved in the local device or will it be retrieved through a web service from a server that contains your database schema?

Comment: Hi TerNovi. I'm hoping to store the scaled down thumnail internally on the device.