# Saving the images in database

Tags: php, mysql

What is the best technique to save images in the mysql database.Should I save images as blob data or save it in directories.The images will be showed every time the user visits his or her profile.
-Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please visit my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9141116/996493)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best technique would be to save them in the file-system and save their paths in the database.

The database is meant for data, the file-system for files.

---

The technique I used in the past to make sure there are no duplicates was to hash the contents of the file and save it as the result, so I get something like:

```
42efb15825666918118ba72128195246dbae4976.jpg
```

The actual name is saved in the database. This was, the chance of having duplicates is negligible.

Comment: if you upload the same file another time, you will have the same hash, no ?

Comment: Exactly, so it prevents duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

The best technique is what Truth said, in addition, to guarantee that your images will have a unique name, use the current timestamp to rename them in your directory.

Comment: I used the user_id as their profile pictures name in the directory....thanks for the help