# display images stored in SQL database

Tags: php, sql, database, image, forms

I have stored images to SQL database with a text box and store it in database no how can I retrieve the image from database. I used the following code to display but its not working

```
// Grab the data from our people table
$sql = "select * from upload";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Could not access DB: " . mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo "<div class=\"picture\">";
  echo "<p>";

  // Note that we are building our src string using the filename from the database
  echo "<img src=$row['data']/>";
  echo $row['title'] . " " . $row['title'] . "<br />";
  echo "</p>";
  echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: HOW are you storing the image? base64 encoded raw image string, or?

Comment: You can found your answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850605/display-image-from-sql

Comment: You are trying to LITERALLY write the image to the database.. that is not how it works. You save the image on a location that the database will know how to find...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display all the images stored inside a database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758548/how-to-display-all-the-images-stored-inside-a-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following link may helps you.

[PHP- Image upload to MySQL](http://staffweb.cms.gre.ac.uk/~mk05/web/PHP/imageUpload.html)

set blob type for data column.