# Output images stored in database MySQL with php

Tags: php, mysql

Snippet:

```
$connect = //connect to db;
$db = $connect->prepare("SELECT profilepicture FROM user WHERE uname = $uname");
$db->execute();
$db->bind_result($img);

...

echo $img;
```

Information:
- I have `image.bin` stored in a column of a table in db
- Opening `image.bin` in hex editor reveals hex codes (File header says it is a PNG file)
- `echo $img` doesn't output the image

Question:
- How to output images that are stored in db?

Comment: question: **how** do you output it **now**? alternatively: how are we supposed to debug code we can't see?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display image from sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850605/display-image-from-sql)

Comment: I'll check it out. Thanks

Comment: Dont' save files in a database. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41235395/267540

Comment: Look! Upload the files in folder and store their names in database! That is the method that should be used

Comment: what is the output ? Have you tried adding the content-type in the headers ? `header("Content-type: image/png");` before the `echo` line

Answer (score 0):

Form

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select image to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

This is how you upload the file

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)){
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}

$img = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

Your insert query
$db = $connect->prepare("UPDATE user SET profilepicture =? WHERE uname = ?");
$db->bind_param("si",$img,$uname);
$db->execute();
```

Taken from w3schools