# How to display images from SQLite database to gridview using Android application

Tags: android, sqlite

I have images in my database and I have converted them into BLOB but I can't display them on a gridview or listview with other information like this: price, QTY, Description, image

Comment: Instead of storing images in to database, i would like to suggest you to store them on sd card and store the path of image in to DB. please visit my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9141116/996493).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in your cursor adapter:

```
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);
byte[] bb = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyBaseColumn.MyTable.ImageField));
myImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bb, 0, bb.length));
```

Comment: Well, we couldn't know that since you didn't post any code.  In that case I have no idea what your issue is.