# How can I store an image in my SQL database?

Tags: android, sql, image, blob

in my app I have set an image from the gallery in an image view. Now I want to store that image in my SQL database.

1. What do I have to change in my SQL database? (BLOB??)
2. What is the best way to retrieve the image from the image view and store it in the SQL Database?

Here is my SQL Database:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
                + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + KEY_TITLE + " text not null, " 
                + KEY_BODY + " text not null, " 
                + KEY_DATE_TIME + " text not null);";
```

Here I get the path of the image in the gallery and then set the image in the image view

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_FILE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

            Log.v("IMAGE PATH====>>>> ",selectedImagePath);

         // Decode, scale and set the image.
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
            Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, NEW_WIDTH, NEW_HEIGHT, true);
            myBitmap.recycle();
            myBitmap = null;

            mImageView.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9141116/996493) might help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first create table like this
db.execSQL("create table if not exists tablename(....,images BLOB,.....);");

then do your java code like this,

```
  ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("your image path here");
  bit.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);

  SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getWritableDatabase();
  ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
  ..
 cv.put("images", outputStream.toByteArray());
 ..
 ..
db.insert("tablename", null, cv);
db.close();
```

this will store your image to db and,

```
byte []temp = c.getBlob(3);
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(temp, 0, temp.length);
BitmapDrawable dd = new BitmapDrawable(image.getImage());
imgView.setBackgroundDrawable(dd);
```

this will retrive image from db..

Comment: hii can you tell me whats the "dbh" SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getWritableDatabase(); in this line.i can't understand..plz help its really help full but i can't understand only this

Comment: dbh is nothing but the object of SQLiteOpenHelper. i hope you have already extends that class to your application for creating database and tables..

Comment: ohkk i understand..and yes i had extended that class

Comment: @kalandar:Hello , maybe you can help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15954896/how-to-save-image-taken-from-camera-and-show-it-to-listview-crashes-with-ille  .Thanks

Answer (score 2):

OR, you save your image on the phone memory(on the SD Card), or Application cache etc.. and you store the path to retrieve your image file in your SQL database.

Comment: I already tried that but i ended up with the problem that you cannot convert a bitmap you set in an image view back to a string (the image path).

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean..
It's up to you to choose your image path (with getExternalCacheDir()+filename), save it with the Bitmap.compress function, and attach it to your imageView with the ImageView. setImageBitmap function

Answer (score 2):

Not a good idea.. You should save the image on the disk to reduce sql operations and to improve application performance.. Saving image in DB will make the database heavy in each sense.. Just store image on disk at desired location and save the path along with image name as string in database table.