# Storing encrypted Data: Encrypted local JSON file vs. encrypted SQLite Database

Tags: android, json, database, sqlite, encryption

I need to store some Data (Questions) because of copyright reasons locally encrypted on the Device. My Process would be: Download raw JSON from Server -> either store it locally encrypted and everytime the App starts I decrypt and parse it or I store it in an encrypted SQLite DB (e.g. with SQLCipher) and access this DB.

What would be the advantages(speed? security?) of those two ways and is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If we overlook encryption in your question, here is a comparison of using flat files vs sqlite in Android: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212640/android-performance-flat-file-vs-sqlite

Comment: So I guess for a larger DataSet (lets say > 500 Entries) it would be probably faster to use the SQLite Database?
I also just found http://sqlcipher.net/blog/2011/5/7/sqlcipher-performance-and-sqlcipherspeed.html so the encryption itself shouldn't be slowing it down that much.