# Using SQLite or a File

Tags: java, android, database, file

I am new to Android development and I am trying to make a Trivia application.

I need to store the data relating to questions somewhere and I am not entirely sure where to store it.

I plan to have multiple people playing so I **need each person to have the same questions**.

Basically I planned to have **a list of categories** and **within each category I had question objects**.

The **question objects contained information regarding the question such as the answers and question** itself.

However, if I use a database, I believe none of this would be needed due the questions being stored in tables which would represent categories.

In terms of speed what would be better:

- to store it in a database
- or to read from a file every time the application is loaded and store the data within a data structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost certainly want a database.  Databases are made for fast search and easy insertion/deletion.  There's really no advantage to having a file and doing in memory parsing each time.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from performance benefits, here's a simple list of advantages of using SQLite rather than flat file:

- You can query items as you wish -- don't need to load all of them and
  select which ones you need.
- Record deletion is a much less painful process. No rewriting of whole
  files into wherever.
- Updating a record is as easy as removing or creating one.
- Have you ever tried doing cross-referencing lookups on a flat file?
  Just.Not.Worth.It.

To summarize, it's every advantage a Database has over a text file.

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12214264/1879661) by josephus